# Is it possible to get a meaningful error message from a GDI+ ExternalException?

Tags: .net, gdi+

I'm working on a image upload feature for a website and I'm doing some processing of these images as they're uploaded so I'm using the `System.Drawing.Image` and other related classes.

Ultimately I'm loading the bitmap data into a `MemoryStream`, from there I'm obtaining my `System.Drawing.Image` and then calling [`Image.Save(string path, ImageFormat format)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx).

I'm finding some JPEGs throw a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException` with the eternally useful error message

> A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Checking the docs for `Image.Save` it states an `ExternalException` will be thrown when

> The image was saved with the wrong image format.
>   -or-
>   The image was saved to the same file it was created from.

The image is a valid JPEG; Preview, Paint, Paint.NET, Photoshop, Chrome and IE all open the file without complaint. My code even opens the file without complaint.

I've tried saving the file with and without a specified `ImageFormat` but I get the same result.

The code works fine for loads of other JPEG files.

**Is there a way to get more information about why the exception is being thrown?**

---

Update

I fear we may be wandering off topic (the topic being, is it possible to get a useful error from a GDI+ ExternalException) so I'm not going to post a repro for the bug I'm experiencing, because ultimately I'm not asking for a fix to that bug.

I think their is significant value in finding a way to get from the nigh-on useless "Generic error in GDI+" to a useful and meaningful error.

Comment: No, that's not possible.  If you need help with this then you'll have to post your code.

Comment: @hanspassant I will do but its not really going to help. Its reproducible in the most basic manner of loading a byte array into a memory stream. Creating an image from that stream then calling save. I think its something in the file but not sure how to discover what. I was hoping by getting a more detailed error from gdi I would be able to find out the issue.